# Most Efficient Way to Find Leftmost div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, position

Using jQuery or straight Javascript, I'm looking for the best way to find the leftmost div (or in general the DOM element with the minimum or maximum position on either axis).

So far I have two solutions:

1. Iterate through the div objects that I want to consider, saving the smallest left position found.
2. Build an array of objects and using javascript's sort() function with a comparison function that looks at the left property, then choosing the 0th element.

I know that solution 1 would be O(N), but I'm not sure what the efficiency of the sort() function is in most browsers, or if there is a completely different approach.

Comment: Sorting is _very_ fast. This will not be the bottleneck, **assuming your comparator function doesn't do any unnecessary work.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

1. you keep track of **one** element and **one** position, you access each element **once**
2. you keep track of **all** elements and access **all** positions **multiple times** because of sorting

What do you think is the fastest? :)

Comment: Well played sir, well played.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not going to do any better than O(n) and the best you'll do pure sorting is O(nlogn). The fastest way would be to walk the DOM. I would call getElementsByTagName("div") and iterate through keeping track of the left most element.

```
function findLeftMostDiv() {
    var leftest = { "left": 999999999999, elem: null };
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for(i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];
        var curleft = findPos(div);
        if(curleft < leftest.left) {
            leftest.left = curleft;
            leftest.elem = div;      
        } 
    } 
    return leftest.elem;               
}

function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft=0;
    if(obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParrent);
    }
    return curleft;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

option 1: iterate through it only once

```
var $smallest = {left: 000000000, item: null};
var $left = 0;
$('selector').each(function(){
    $left = $(this).offset().left;
    if ($left < $smallest.left)
    {
        $smallest.left = $left;
        $smallest.item = this;
    }
});
```

option 2: iterate through it at least twice

```
var $array = [];
$('selector').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $array.push({left: $this.offset().left, item: this});
});
$array.sort(function(a,b){
    if (a.left < b.left) return -1;
    if (a.left > b.left) return 1;
    return 0;
});
// smallest is $array[0]
```

option 1 is always faster in this case since you only have to sort it while selecting, sorting almost comes for free in that case.

edit: of course, using only the DOM for this is again, way faster.